# Towers of Hanoi with more than 3 pegs

Tags: computer-science, towers-of-hanoi

I understand the standard recursion solution for towers of Hanoi over [here](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~cburch/survey/recurse/hanoiimpl.html).

But what if I have a variable number of pegs and disks? Will the solution provided [here](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~cburch/survey/recurse/hanoiimpl.html) always be the shortest (aka fastest) path from one tower to another? If yes, why?

Comment: Obviously not. If there are more pegs than disks, you can solve it by moving each disk to a different spare peg, then move them all to the target. However, maybe that could be the base case of the recursion.

Comment: Is there an algorithm for the fastest path out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi#With_four_pegs_and_beyond) says

> the optimal solution for the Tower of Hanoi problem with four pegs (called Reve's puzzle), let alone more pegs, is still an open problem.

I found this in 5 seconds of googling "generalized tower of hanoi problem".

Comment: Homework guy clearly got lost seeing Altavista is closing down, didn't know where to search